# PHP & Skype integration on ubuntu

Tags: php, api, skype, skype4com

I just started looking at skype developer api to wrap skype  sms sending in web application.

I just want to send and receieve skype messages using web application .

I have some question here .

1. I am developing on Ubuntu(Linux) .Is it possible to develop skype application over ubuntu.
2. Skype4com contains a dll file is der any alternative of that for Linux .
3. I want to send Skype message to the users without installing skype on my system.
4. Any tutorial or example will be helpfull .

Please help  and suggest me the better way to do this .

Thank

Comment: You can't use COM on GNU/Linux.

Comment: Yes i know that is what i posted q here

Answer (score 2):

There is a linux skype api which may do part of what you need:
http://dev.skype.com/desktop-api-reference#Linux

However it requires a running skype client on the sending box. (As it is a way to send commands to the skype client, not a way to send out commands directly). And I cant see a way to send a login request to that client, so you will need to ensure that skype is running and logged in as the required user. Finally you will need to click on something in skype to authorise your application to control skype.

Comment: The name ubuntu is not present in that list

Comment: Actually Fiesty Fawn (which is on the list) is a specific version of ubuntu.

Comment: Oh Fiesty Fwan  let me try